# Need help to auto indent in verilog or systemverilog code in VIM

Tags: vim, verilog, system-verilog

---

```
initial begin
if () begin
a=b;
c=d;
end
else begin
c=d;
c=a;
end
end
```

I have already tried, **gg=G** or **selecting code and =** is not working.
Could you please help me here. code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the filetype to `verilog` by `:set filetype=verilog`. Or you can save the file as `tmp.v` and reopen it.

Below is from `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` which defines the relationship between filetype and file extension.

```
" Vera
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.vr,*.vri,*.vrh      setf vera

" Verilog HDL
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.v           setf verilog

" Verilog-AMS HDL
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.va,*.vams       setf verilogams

" SystemVerilog
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sv,*.svh        setf systemverilog

" VHDL
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.hdl,*.vhd,*.vhdl,*.vbe,*.vst,*.vho  setf vhdl
```

Comment: It might be useful to mention that all that checking and setting is done automatically when you have, at minimum, `syntax on` or `filetype on` in your `vimrc`.

Comment: I have did the changes mentioned above its not helping. or I missed anything not sure.

Comment: After `set filetype=verilog`, did the file highlighting look different then? Which vim version are you using?

Comment: After **set filetype==verilog**, code highlighting is not changing. I am using below vim version.

**VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar  8 2017 11:07:09)**
**Included patches: 1-314**

Comment: **set filetype=verilog**, please ignore my above syntax error

Comment: You can add `filetype plugin indent on` and
`syntax enable` to your `vimrc` and see if it works.